# change date type in sas output table

Tags: sas

In the following sas codes..

```
data temp2;
input id 1 @3 date mmddyy11.;
cards;
1 11/12/1980
2 10/20/1996
3 12/21/1999
;
run;

proc print data = temp2;
format date date9.;
run;
```

Rsults in :

```
id         date

 1    12NOV1980
 2    20OCT1996
 3    21DEC1999
```

Consider the following output and date type:

```
data temp3a;
set temp2;
two_days = intnx('day',date,2);
run;
proc print data = temp3a noobs;
format date two_days date9.;
run;
```

Result

```
id         date     two_days

 1    12NOV1980    14NOV1980
 2    20OCT1996    22OCT1996
 3    21DEC1999    23DEC1999
```

**What I want is that the output date should be in the following format:**

```
id         date     two_days

 1    12NOV80    14NOV80
 2    20OCT96    22OCT96
 3    21DEC99    23DEC99
```

**Also when I perform the following:**

```
data have01211;
set WORK.XX;
two_days_before = intnx('day', Date, -2);
two_days_after = intnx('day', Date, 2);
run;

proc print data = have01211 noobs;
format two_days_before two_days_after date8.;
run;
```

The result i get is as follows:

```
two_days_before two_days_after
20764   20768
20758   20762
20763   20767
20730   20734
```

**Why this?? Why not same format as in original data?**

Comment: i think I am getting out for two_days_before two_days_after as numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question - just modify the format as follows:

```
data temp3a;
set temp2;
two_days = intnx('day',date,2);
run;
proc print data = temp3a noobs;
format date two_days date8.; /* shorter date format length */
run;
```

Regarding the second question - you are applying the format in the `proc print` but not the dataset (am presuming you are talking about `have01211`).  Simply attach a format to those variables in the data step as follows:

```
data have01211;
  set WORK.temp2;
  two_days_before = intnx('day', Date, -2);
  two_days_after = intnx('day', Date, 2);
  format two_days_before two_days_after date8.;
run;
```

**Explanation** - when you apply a format in a proc print, it only applies to that print step.  If you add a format when creating a dataset, it is stored permanently with that dataset - so in fact you won't need a format statement in any subsequent `proc print`'s:

```
proc print data = have01211 noobs;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubts and correction to my mistakes.